# VS2019 sign in to azure throws: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2019, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-group

Visual studio 2019 throws the error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." after sign in to azure.

I created new solution for Azure Resource Group on .Net Framework v4.8.
I selected Logic App template. Using Logic app design extension the visual studio required of me to sign in to azure, select subscription and select Reserource group.

What is the reason of throwing that exception and how can I sign in?

The resource group name and solution group name are different.
I'm not sure if this might be the problem reason.

[image: Sign in window]

[image: Solution explorer]

Comment: Did you update to the latest Visual Studio and extension version? This is a product bug, not something that can be fixed with code. It can only be fixed by installing an updated version

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019 v16.11.5 which is the newest. I'll try to downgrade it

Comment: I've just installed VS2019 v16.10.4 and it works. Moreover it works now for the version 16.11.5. It's possible that restarting visual studio worked for fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad that @Dawid Sieczka was able to solve this issue. This is a product bug, as @Panagiotis Kanavos highlighted. Posting this as an answer to assist other members of the community who may be experiencing similar problems.

> According to this [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-logic-apps-with-visual-studio#prerequisites) here is one of the prerequisites for the environment.
>
> Download and install these tools, if you don't have them already:
> Visual Studio 2019, 2017, or 2015 - Community edition or greater.

You can try the below methods if you face any similar issues:

1. Determine whether the problem has been a known one.
2. Check with the developer community.
3. Try to repair Visual Studio.
4. To resolve upgrade issues, delete the Visual Studio Installer folder.
5. Make an issue report.
6. Delete the installation files for Visual Studio.
7. Chat Assistance.
8. Upgrade or Downgrade the version according to the deprecation of the software.

**RESOURCES:**

[Troubleshoot installation or upgrade issues - Visual Studio (Windows) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues?view=vs-2019)